# When does Chrome stop show loading status at the top of its tab?

Tags: google-chrome, website

While opening a wbsite in Chrome, there will be a loading status at the top of its tab. I am curious about its logic. When does it stop showing this loading status? After the html is fully loaded? After all the images are loaded? Any clue? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You mean technically, or observably? I find it takes longer to complete the animation than refresh the page. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi98G.gif [there are two consecutive refreshes, the 2nd barely shows because the gif frame-rate isn't fast enough. It was visible 'live'.] Note the animation still has to finish long after the page is drawn. On a page where DNS has to be fetched first, the animation is initially an empty circle; once the page load starts, it becomes the animated circle in the gif, which then takes longer than the page.

Comment: Hi, I mean techically. Prevously, I thought it will be stop loading after the DOM framework is loaded. But it seems not...